# Forcing portrait layout in iPhone app - bad idea?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am not an experienced iPhone user, so I have a question regarding to nice way of handling portrait/landscape layouts in my application.

Thing is that my current ui is designed the way that it doesn't quite fit/usable in landscape layout. So, is this a common for iPhone app to force portrait layout or this is totally a bad idea and it is better to invest in redesigning ui?

Also, if this is a common approach - is there a standard, solid way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok to have an application only in portrait (there are so many in the app store...). Even applications from Apple itself sometimes only allow portrait, for example the App Store. Keep an eye for this in your code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

By default it will only allow portrait. On the iPad case, it's more common to have both portrait and landscape, but still you can make it only portrait.